# Linear algebra and Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the problem of fitting a polynomial of order p to n + 1 data points

($x_0$, $y_0$), ($x_1$, $y_1$), . . . ($x_n$, $y_n$) :

that is, find a polynomial

$p(x)$ = $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^
2$ + · · · + $a_p x^
p$
,

such that each ($x_j , y_j$ ) fits the polynomial exactly, so $y_j = p(x_j )$.

(a) The problem is to find the coefficients $a_i$
. Explain why the problem is linear and
write it in the matrix form $M v = w$, expressing each of these in terms of the ($x_j , y_j$ )
and $a_i$
. The matrix M is known as a $Vandermonde$ $matrix$.

I know what is Vandermonde Matrix but I'm stuck on explaining this is linear and writing the matrix form , how should I start a good approach to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Start with $(x_0,y_0)$. That is, $p(x_0) = y_0$. So,$$a_0 + x_0a_1 + x_0^2a_2 + \ldots+ x_0^pa_p = y_0.$$That's a linear equation with unknowns $a_1,\ldots,a_p$. Do that for any data point and you will get your linear system. The first row of the matrix will thus be $(1,x_0,x_0^2,\ldots,x_0^p)$.